# Unity iOS game crashing with NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, game-center

I am using Prime31's GameCenter Turn Based plugin in my game in order to handle online matches.
 A problem arises when I receive an "invitation to play" notification from Game Center while Game Center's matchmaker is showing (called using the plug-in => `GameCenterTurnBasedBinding.findMatch(2,2,false);` ).

The app crashes and the following output is shown in Xcode:

```
2012-08-20 08:39:27.050 Cabrais[1808:707] *** Assertion failure in -[NSIndexPath row], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-1914.85/UITableViewSupport.m:2606
2012-08-20 08:39:27.052 Cabrais[1808:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid index path for use with UITableView. Index paths passed to table view must contain exactly two indices specifying the section and row. Please use the category on NSIndexPath in UITableView.h if possible.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x355ec88f 0x33210259 0x355ec789 0x349e03a3 0x32d4d673 0x35dba49d 0x35dd90e5 0x35dd9379 0x32d4cefb 0x32d4bfd9 0x32d4b763 0x35da7657 0x32ceff37 0x3554b1fb 0x32716aa5 0x327166bd 0x327165c9 0x35dd8179 0x35da936b 0x35dbce65 0x35dbb6b3 0x33979c59 0x33984e91 0x355bf2ad 0x355424a5 0x3554236d 0x332dd439 0x32d1acd5 0x6954 0x3388)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

I have tried disabling notifications through the Ipad/Iphone settings for both my app and GameCenter as well as through the code by removing all notification related code but this hasn't had any effect at all.

I know through debugging that the code in my function attached to GameCenterTurnBasedManager.handleTurnEventEvent doesn't get called before the crash occurs, and neither does the one registered to EtceteraManager.remoteNotificationReceived. (Both these function work perfectly fine otherwise.)

I have asked Prime31 and they have told me that the exception is a mishandling of the tables data source, and to file a bug report with Apple.

Has anyone experienced a similar crash/error while working with Unity?
And is there any way I can try to catch the notification before it arrives and remove the matchmaker or be able to handle the error from unity?

Any insight/help/comments would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks.